# Does set interval and observers slow down my angular app?

Tags: angular, observable, setinterval

I have code that looks like this and I am just wondering if this will bloat my app? Or make it slow in one way or another?

```
  // so that anytime the user changes their wallet it reflects on the view
  connectedAddress$ = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(this.signerAddress), 1000);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will steal at max 10 nanoseconds of CPU every second, which is not significant, even if you have several hundreds of such subscriptions. The bad thing in this one, is that you don't stop this interval at all. so if for example this connectedAdress$ gets a subscribtion in some component template, and you render 1000 components, and then rerender them multiple times, these garbage intervals will accumulate and will take a noticable part of your memory and maybe even CPU. The correct way would be to use built in rxjs operators and factories for your needs. for this particular use case `interval(1000)` is better.

```
connectedAddress$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(() => this.signerAddress));
```

but even better thing would be to make a subject for your signer address, and, whenever it changes update the subject value

```
this.signerAddress$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

updateAddress(address) {this.signerAddress.next(address)}
```

Comment: I tried making a subject but it did not work. The subject did not emit any changes. Also, why are the rxjs `interval` operator better than `setInterval()` ?

Comment: because it contains unsubscription logic, and it would be disposed when you unsubscribe  of observable, while your custom one's setInterval will be spamming forever